# Why is Visual Studio Installer putting some dependencies in not as dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've created a new MSI installer project. The *only* files I added are the EXE, PDB and app config file from their bin folder (highlighted in red):

[image]

It has done a decent job of picking up dependencies though it appears to have included some system assemblies from C:\windows... and packaged them.

But more curiously, System.Buffers.DLL and two others at the bottom were auto-added, but *not* as dependencies. On the other hand, System.Threading.Channels.DLL is not a system DLL (I'm using Framework 4.6) but was listed under dependency.

Why would it add detected dependencies and what should I do about this? I haven't used this project type before and am unsure how much manual hacking I should be doing.

Comment: I guess it happens because these assemblies are retrieved from nuget. Or you have `CopyLocal` set to `true` for them

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski which ones? It seems a total mix. The one Framework assembly I explicitly _do_ want, it doesn't include!

Comment: Because it is an obsolete technology and you should get rid of it, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d

Comment: @Mr.Boy I can recommend to use a WiX toolset to build a new MSI installer. It allows you to control which dlls should be included to packages, at least